# Is there an "Deliver report by email" equivalent for SearchKit?

Tags: email, civireport, searchkit

CiviCRM provides an api by which we can create Scheduled Jobs to send CiviReport output via email on scheduled basis.

Is there any out-of-the-box functionality (probably via an extension, I would guess), that would provide similar behavior for SearchKit output from a saved search?

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seem to be an extension, but see this [recent discussion on chat](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/h4y4umg1qtdriyokb76fsexfpy) for an option from [Demerit](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/users/181/demerit), which I'm pasting here:

"I don't recommend this as a real solution, but for something quick and dirty you can put this in a file and schedule it with cron. Adjust params as needed."

```
#!/bin/sh  
cv api4 --user=admin_cms_user SearchDisplay.download savedSearch=saved_search_name display=search_display_name format=csv > report.csv  
echo "some text for the body" | mail -s "here you go" -S "from=info@myorg.org" -a report.csv recipient@example.com
rm -f report.csv
```