Events newsletter communications?
I've got a WordPress (currently 6.5.5) CiviCRM (currently 5.74.4) setup. Trying to find some way to allow users to subscribe to an email newsletter to be notified of any newly created events in CiviCRM. I also have JetPack which has a newsletter function, but that's only for WordPress posts or pages; also using WpForo for forums but that's not even integrated with JetPack's newsletter. The goal is for people who have signed up as members to the website (CiviCRM controls that, but of course you log in via WordPress) to be able to get notified of any new events, as they may not visit the website that frequently. New events are the primary driver, but really the goal is to send a recurring email (or on-demand) to whomever's subscribed to a notification list whenever something of note occurs, but it would have to have a central subscription configuration following the law around unsubscribe options... so I'm just looking to solve that for CiviCRM as that's where the meat of the content comes from.
I've found there's the Advanced Newsletter Plugin but that's not even showing up in CiviCRM's Add New extension page, and it's unclear to me based on the documentation that it would do what I want or even work in WordPress vs. Drupal.
I've found some other information via googling that tells me I have to be missing something pretty obvious, but even with that knowledge and triple checking everything before I post this, any resolution is still eluding me... Any friendly nudges to what I'm missing would be appreciated. Thanks.
Michael

We have used SearchKit to create output and set it to be sent (to admins) on a regular basis. I don't recall if we had to customise, and if we did whether that customisation was accepted upstream. But it means the 'send a report on a regular basis' option is possible. I don't know how hard the 'and send to a Smart Group or Public Group' would be but assume not hard. The first question then is can SearchKit build the sort of report you would consider 'acceptable' as a mailing?

note. iirc we used the 'quick and dirty' mentioned here as a starting point: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45511/is-there-an-deliver-report-by-email-equivalent-for-searchkit

Thanks for the suggestion. The query I'm looking for is basically any event that was created in the past week OR starts in the next month, which would also need to just show the specific instances of any recurring events that match that criteria. Adding criteria always gets AND'd, even if you choose "OR."
Your idea of having a cron job with either a SearchKit API call is interesting, but am still not seeing how to tie a mailing that needs to allow users to subscribe or unsubscribe to the SearchKit results, without basically writing most of that from scratch as a cron job.
